# Retopology of high-poly terrain with the conform tool in Maya

Tags: 3d, maya

I have a high-polygon mesh of a scan of some terrain I'm trying to retopologize to low-polygon mesh. It's unrealistic to assume I can manually use the quad-draw tool to do this. So I'm using the conform tool with a subdivided plane, which works well for a large majority of the mesh; but it's giving me problems for parts of the terrain that have concave cliff-like features. I have tried using quad-draw and subdividing a simple retop, but quad-draw does not recalculate the subdivisions to match the terrain. What can I do? Are there other techniques? Shrinkwrap?

[The terrain I want to retop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OjiW.png)

[The conform tool.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc8sP.png)

[The result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypgck.png)

Comment: Did you try the polyreduce tool?

Comment: We already reduced the mesh. Now we need to retopologize it so it can be unwrapped and baked.